# Autofac ASP.NET Core Multitenant: Can't call IServiceCollection extensions on per-tenant ContainerBuilder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autofac, multi-tenant

I want to make a multitenant ASP.NET Core application. I'm following the [documentation](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#multitenant-support) and I'm at the point where I call

```
var mtc = new MultitenantContainer(container.Resolve<ITenantIdentificationStrategy>(), container);

mtc.ConfigureTenant(
    tenant.Name,
    builder=>
    {
        // register per-tenant services here
    });
```

I want to register a database connection per tenant. The library I'm using provides an extension method on `IServiceCollection` so regularely, I would call `services.AddDataBase()` but in the lambda, the `builder` parameter is of type `ContainerBuilder` so naturaly the extensions don't work here.

Is there a way to maybe convert the `builder` to a `IServiceCollection` to be able to call the extension method? Or is the only way to go through the implementation of the extension method and duplicate the whole logic?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a fairly easy way:

```
mtc.ConfigureTenant(
    tenant.Name,
    builder =>
    {
        IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();

        services.AddDataBase();

        builder.Populate(services);
    });
```

Instead of converting the builder to a `IServiceCollection`, I instantiate a new one and then use the `Populate()` extension method on the `ContainerBuilder` to copy the bindings over.

Comment: I think this is the best you're going to get on this; I was going to recommend trying that but you already found it. Just be aware [you'll also get a per-tenant `IServiceProvider` and `IServiceScopeFactory`](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection/blob/develop/src/Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection/AutofacRegistration.cs#L96) which is probably OK, but... if you see weird stuff, keep that in the back of your mind.